# Counting how many time a relation is pointing at the same key

Tags: mysql, count, foreign-key-relationship, database-relations

```
SELECT t.tag_name
FROM tags t
 JOIN resource_tags rt ON rt.tag_id = t.tag_id
 JOIN resource r ON r.resource_id = rt.resource_id
 JOIN visitor_resource vr ON vr.resource_id = rt.resource_id
 JOIN visitor v ON v.visitor_id = vr.visitor_id
WHERE v.visitor_id = '1'
GROUP BY t.tag_name
```

As you might see, a 'visitor' visits a 'resource' and a relation between them will be created in visitor_resource.

A given 'resource' have a couple of 'tags' depending on the content, and they are bound together by a relation in resource_tags.

The above query outputs the tag-names for all the resources that a visitor have visited.

Now I want to find out how many times a tag is represented.

Consider the following:
Resource 1: tag1, tag2
Resource 2: tag1
Resource 3: tag2
Resource 4: tag1

The query should output:
tag1, 3
tag2, 2

I have tried with the following:

```
SELECT t.tag_name, SUM(t.tag_id) as cnt
 FROM tags t
 JOIN resource_tags rt ON rt.tag_id = t.tag_id
 JOIN visitor_resource vr ON vr.resource_id = rt.resource_id
 JOIN visitor v ON v.visitor_id = vr.visitor_id
WHERE v.visitor_id = '2'
GROUP BY t.tag_name
```

But that seems to have exceptionally unreasonable high numbers for cnt, and not counting for this specific user.

Is this even possible with MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use: `COUNT(t.tag_id)`

and not `SUM(t.tag_id)`.

It's also more common to group by the id (primary key) and perhaps faster as the index can be used for the grouping. The tag_name may not have an index.

```
SELECT t.tag_name
     , COUNT(t.tag_id) AS cnt
FROM tags t
  JOIN resource_tags rt ON rt.tag_id = t.tag_id
  JOIN visitor_resource vr ON vr.resource_id = rt.resource_id
  JOIN visitor v ON v.visitor_id = vr.visitor_id
WHERE v.visitor_id = '2'
GROUP BY t.tag_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a SUM on the ID, not a COUNT.

You're basically adding up the auto-generated values of your tags, which is going to give you a much higher result than simply adding up the occurrences.

Comment: Dude, mistakes like this happen to all of us.  I've lost count of the times when I've done the exact opposite boolean operation to what I intended :)

Answer (score 1):

It appears your problem might because you are doing SUM instead of COUNT

```
SELECT t.tag_name, COUNT(t.tag_id) as cnt
```

instead of

```
SELECT t.tag_name, SUM(t.tag_id) as cnt
```

should do it.